# CKEditor add CSS styling to Preview and Editor

Tags: css, class, ckeditor, customization

Is it possible to add CSS to style the Editor text as well as the Preview?

The CMS has a different set of CSS files from the public part of the website and I want the editor to try (at least) and reflect the way it would look in the site.

For example, all  tags with a class of .floatLeft{float:left;margin:0 10px 10px 0;} I want to look the same in the Editor.

Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Setup [CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.contentsCss) variable.
[CKEDITOR.config.bodyClass](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.bodyClass) and [CKEDITOR.config.bodyId](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.bodyId) could help too.
These are only options you have (i think).

Comment: yes that is what I was looking for `config.contentsCss = '/css/mysitestyles.css';
config.contentsCss = ['/css/mysitestyles.css', '/css/anotherfile.css'];`

Answer (score 6):

To be more exact, you can edit your ckeditor/plugins/styles/styles/default.js and add in files something like { name : 'FloatLeft', element : 'span', attributes : { 'class' : 'floatleft' }}.

Then you add to your ckeditor/contents.css (if you decided to use the editor style) or in your own style.css the class declaration .floatLeft{float:left;margin:0 10px 10px 0;}

Do not forget to clear the browser cache after saving :)

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks, Ravaka. I don't want to change the CORE files. Just config it.