# How to make same css in ckeditor and it's publish?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, ckeditor, styling

I am using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
I am editing and styling elements in its own window successfully.

But when i save it to DB (html data) and than get to my website from DB;
than of course my website styles.css is different from css that showing in ckeditor on editing.

**How can i make same css (same view) on ckeditor edit window and my div in website (publish)?**

Should i reset.css both? but how can i prevent css overrides from my site.css?

Comment: well its clear from the code above that you are using a parallel server with a nosql database, so of course the returning value will be binary and so display penguins instead of html .

Comment: The question is not sql or db or etc. >The question is i styling my html elements on my ckeditor and saving it as html. Then when i use this styling html in my website, my website .css is overrides my custom editing elements, so how can i prevent my html that editing on ckeditor from my website.css overrides? (so the screen VIEW is not same in ckeditor and my website)

Comment: I was just trying to point out that you should add the code you have used, it helps a lot. Even better if you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) it up .not all of us a magicians

Comment: I believe that this answers your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046408/ckeditor-4-combinate-css

Comment: its close, thanks, i will try this answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608084/ckeditor-add-css-styling-to-preview-and-editor